# Openserver + composer через proxy?

Tags: proxy, composer, openserver

Как понимаю современному разработчику без композера никуда. Но у меня такая ситуация - ось Вин 7 х64. То есть разрабатываю на OpenServer через его консоль (потому что НетБинс только локально файлы видит). Но на работе стоит прокси. Дома композер ставится без проблем.
На работе получаю такую ошибку

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: fai
led to open stream: ??????? ?????????? ?????????? ???? ???????????, ?.?. ??
??????? ?????????? ?? ????????? ????? ?? ??????? ?????? ??????, ??? ???? ?
???????? ??? ????????????? ?????????? ??-?? ????????? ??????? ??? ?????????
???? ??????????.
```

видел предлагают в переменные среды добавить параметры. добавлял - не помогло? кто сталкивался и как боролся?

Comment: Вручную этот файл грузится?

Comment: да вполне{"packages":[],"notify":"\/downloads\/%package%","notify----

Comment: Проверяйте настройки php, всякие fopen wrappers. По-хорошему ПО на компе system-wide прокси вообще не должно замечать.

Comment: openserver с теми же настройками из дома лезет на ура.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать консоль openserver но нужно указать прокси

```
    set http_proxy=http://myproxy.ru:5987/
```